# How to block until an event occurs in an RX stream?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

With Microsoft Reavtive Extensions (RX), I'm wondering if its possible to block until an event occurs?

Somthing like this:

```
observableStream.BlockUntilTrue(o => o.MyProperty == true);
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried `observableStream.TakeUntil(o => o.MyProperty == true);`, but this exits immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have rewritten my answer after reading your comments. In your case you can use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229177(v=vs.103).aspx) but it changes the asynchronous nature of RX into synchronous code that blocks. I guess that is what your question is about.

```
var firstValue = observableStream.
  .Where(o => o.MyProperty)
  .First();
```

The call to `First` will block and wait for the first value to arrive from the observable sequence which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am writing a console application that waits until a certain event occurs, then continues execution. Surely there must be a way for one thread to wait wait until an event occurs, which means it can continue execution?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have found a method that seems to work well for the quick test suite that I am writing, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It's a bad idea to block. You should avoid it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This demo code works well. It adds an extension method that blocks until a single event occurs on the stream. If a timeout was added to the Take() for the BlockingCollection, it would wait until either an event occurred, or a timeout occurred.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RX_2
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Subject<bool> stream = new Subject<bool>();

            Task.Run(
                () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
                        stream.OnNext(false);
                    }
                    stream.OnNext(true);
                });

            Console.Write("Start\n");
            stream.Where(o => o == true).BlockUntilEvent();
            Console.Write("Stop\n");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void BlockUntilEvent(this IObservable<bool> stream)
        {
            BlockingCollection<bool> blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<bool>();
            stream.Subscribe(blockingCollection.Add);
            var result = blockingCollection.Take();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small thing, but I'd have thought `Task.Delay` would be preferable to `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: This code uses Microsoft Reactive Extensions (RX). It won't compile unless you add this using NuGet.